# can't locate node [moveit_setup_assistant] in package [moveit_setup_assistant]

Tags: ros, moveit, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because the moveit is updated recently.So I use "sudo apt-get remove ros-indigo-moveit" to remove moveit.And then I used "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit" to reinstall moveit.It can be found in http://moveit.ros.org/install/ .

After that I open a new terminal. I can rospack find  moveit_setup_assistant in opt/ros/indigo/share.

But when I  run “roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch” It appeared error

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant]: can't locate node [moveit_setup_assistant] in package [moveit_setup_assistant]
```

After I run "`source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`" in the terminal.The moveit_setup_assistant works well.

I must source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash can I use moveit_setup_assistant.However, after source /opt/...,I can't rospack find the packages in catkin_ws.So after source /opt/...When I run `move_group.launch`, It appeared error.

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [moveit_ros_move_group/move_group]: can't locate node [move_group] in package [moveit_ros_move_group]
```

I must source `~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` can I use the packages in catkin_ws. However this way I can't use setup_assistant.launch

The bottom lines of my ~/.bashrc file is

```
source /home/robot508/catkin_ws/catkin_industrial/devel/setup.bash 
source /home/robot508/catkin_ws/le_myself/devel/setup.bash 
source /home/robot508/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

When I add the source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash to the last line,It also can't work. How can I  find the `moveit_setup_assistant.launch` and `move_group.launch` at the same time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251251/can%27t-locate-node-%5Bmoveit_setup_assistant%5D-in-package-%5Bmoveit_setup_assistant%5D/) by [Lileping](https://answers.ros.org/users/28761/lileping/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2017-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> source /home/robot508/catkin_ws/catkin_industrial/devel/setup.bash
> source /home/robot508/catkin_ws/le_myself/devel/setup.bash
> source /home/robot508/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

First, you're nesting catkin workspace (ie. placing workspaces into another workspace). While it's technically possible (I confirmed that `catkin_make` runs as intended for each workspace), I suggest not do that unless you really need to and you know what you're doing, because this may cause unexpected result (instead the normal way to use multiple catkin workspaces is to place each separately).

And your issue sounds like your catkin workspace might not be configured as it's supposed to. Remove `build` and `devel` folders in %YOUR_CATKIN_WS% and run catkin_make, source the setup again to see if it works. Your uncommon workspace setting might have done something funky so again I suggest you fix it.

If the issue persists you need to share more info esp. `env|grep ROS`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lileping](https://answers.ros.org/users/28761/lileping/) on 2017-01-05**:
Thank you very much. You are right. The nesting catkin workspace is uncommon. I rebuild my catkin workspace and now moveit works well. Thanks a lot